# How to insert Analytics events inside script tag

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics

I have a Wordpress site and I activated a WhatsApp chat plugin. I want to track when people click on that button, but I don't know hot to insert the:

```
ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);
```

Inside the code of the plugin:

```
<!-- WhatsHelp.io widget -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var options = {
            whatsapp: "+XXXXXXXXX", // WhatsApp number
            company_logo_url: "//example.com", // URL of company logo (png, jpg, gif)
            greeting_message: "xxxxx", // Text of greeting message
            call_to_action: "xxxxx", // Call to action
            position: "right", // Position may be 'right' or 'left'
        };
        var proto = document.location.protocol, host = "whatshelp.io", url = proto + "//static." + host;
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
        s.onload = function () { WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options); };
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    })();
</script>
<!-- /WhatsHelp.io widget -->
```

I tried putting this line:

```
s.onclick = function () { ga('send', 'event', 'WhatsApp', 'whatsappclick'); };
```

But doesn't works.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the link of the page where this is live?

Comment: The link is www.synergyo2.pe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here s is creating the script tag not the button which is the reason your code is not working. 
A small hack can be done here because the class of the whatsapp button is fixed and unique.
Put this inside the s.onload function. The only requirement here is that you load your ga script before this script.

```
var whatsapp_button = document.getElementsByClassName("wh-widget-button wh-widget-button-activator");
whatsapp_button[0].onclick = function () { ga('send', 'event', 'WhatsApp', 'whatsappclick'); };
```